Lorentz Boosts and Hyperbolic Quaternions
How do you use the Hyperbolic Quaternion formula for a Lorentz Boost? I'm refering to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_quaternion :
$$t' + x'r = (\cosh(a) t + x\sinh(a)) + (\sinh(a) t + x\cosh(a))r$$
with a being the rapidity, $x$ and t the initial $x$- and $t$-coordinate and $r$ being a unit vector.
When I'm trying to use the formula and compare it to other ways for solving (e.g. using the Lorentz factor), I always end up with different results.
Example:
A point $\mathbf{P} = (t,x)$ in inertial system I should be translated to inertial system I'. I observes that I' has a speed of $v$ and is only moving parallel to the $x$-axis of I.
I used: $t = 10$ years, $x = 10$ light years and $v$ being 0.866c.
When solving with the formula $$t' = \gamma (t - x v/c^2)$$ and $$x' = \gamma (x - v t)$$ I get $t'$ = approx. 2.7 years and $x'$ = approx. 2.7 light years. However, when solving with the hyperbolic quaternion formula, I get totally different results.
So how do I apply the formula correctly?

I'd never heard of hyperbolic quaternions, and they seem very strange – not even an alternative algebra, which is worse than the octonions. The subspace $a+br$ is isomorphic to the split-complex numbers, which are better behaved. If you're interested in a 3+1 dimensional generalization of that, I think you're better off with the biquaternions, or with Clifford algebras, of which the biquaternions are a special case.
In any case, the Lorentz transformation with hyperbolic trig functions that you wrote down has nothing to do with any of those algebras as such. It's just a standard Lorentz transformation using rapidity, and could equally be written
$$\begin{eqnarray} t' &=& t \cosh α + x \sinh α \\ x' &=& x \cosh α + t \sinh α \end{eqnarray}$$
You didn't say what wrong result you got. The problems I see are that you have $x'$ and $t'$ backwards (it should be $t'+x'r$), and your Lorentz transform with $v$ has the opposite sign, so you'd need to use $α<0$ for $v>0$, or flip the sign of the $\sinh$ terms. You should use $α = \pm \tanh^{-1} 0.866 \approx \pm1.32$.

Thank you for replying. I've now used approx. -1.32 for the rapidity and it works. I've realized as well that I have to replace t with t * c and t' with t' * c in the formula with the hyperbolic trig. functions. (Please correct me if I'm wrong.)
