Why is it not possible to describe general Lorentz Boosts using Hyperbolic Quaternions?
The Lorentz Boosts (for 1+1D) can be described by the Split-Complex Numbers. A Lorentz Boost in the direction of $x$ with the rapidity $\alpha$ for a 1+1D-system can be calculated using
$$q \mapsto e^{\alpha i} q.$$
Note that $i$ is the imaginary unit of the Split-Complex Numbers. The Hyperbolic Quaternions are a generalization of them, defined as $q = a + bi + cj + dk$ with $$i^2 = +1, j^2 = +1, k^2 = +1.$$
The other combinations between $i, j$ and $k$ follow the pattern of the ordinary Quaternions. Furthermore, the polar form of a Hyperbolic Quaternion uses the hyperbolic functions $\sinh$ and $\cosh$, a hyperbolic angle $\alpha$ and a (hyperbolic) Unit Quaternion $\epsilon$:
$$e^{\alpha \epsilon} = \cosh{\alpha} + \epsilon \sinh{\alpha}$$

Interestingly, and that's also part of the reason why I'm asking this question, Biquaternions (complexified Quaternions) can be used to formulate a general pure Lorentz Boost using a similar polar form (this is not the general polar form as this is only a Boost, not a general Lorentz-Transformation) which is
$$e^{\alpha h \mu} = (\cosh{\alpha} + h \mu \sinh{\alpha}),$$ using again the hyperbolic angle $\alpha$ and a Unit Quaternion $\mu$. The formula for the Lorentz Boost is the following:
$$q \mapsto (\cosh{\frac{\alpha}{2}} + h \mu \sinh{\frac{\alpha}{2}})\space q \space (\cosh{\frac{\alpha}{2}} + h \mu \sinh{\frac{\alpha}{2}}),$$
$\alpha$ being the rapidity in the direction $\mu = xi + yj + zk$ and $h$ being the imaginary unit of the complex coefficients.

Now when searching for a general Lorentz Boost formula with Hyperbolic Quaternions, I'm not able to find one and Wikipedia only states the special case formula from above with the Split-Complex Numbers. Still, the needed Biquaternions have a quite similar polar form compared to the one of the Hyperbolic Quaternions. Apart from the missing imaginary unit $h$ and the differences when simplifying $i^2, j^2$ or $k^2$, what are the reasons why there's no general Lorentz Boost formula with Hyperbolic Quaternions or if there is, how does the formula look like?

Related posts by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/817681/2451 & https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/823656/2451

If I had  to guess I'd say it's simply lack of interest; most textbooks (and physicists) use ordinary 4-vector notation. There is some interest in spacetime algebras. But in general it's not clear to me that there's any additional benefit from the added structure (and complexity) of hyperbolic quaternions over the other approaches.

The very wiki link you linked to, said that hyperbolic quaternions can describe any general Lorentz boost. I think it is trying to say that it cannot deal with rotations (or if it can, then mirror symmetry or something else) that blocks it from describing the Lorentz group in general.

rapidity is traditionally $\omega = \tanh^{-1}\beta$, while $\alpha=\tan^{-1}\beta$ being the angle between the stationary and boosted coordinate axises in a Minkowski diagram.

@naturallyInconsistent Yes, I've read that too but if $r$ is the direction of the boost in any direction, why is $r$ multiplied with $x$ in $e^{\alpha r} (t + xr)$? This doesn't make sense to me, wouldn't that formulation only work if the boost is in $x$- (or $y$- or $z$-) direction only?

No, it will work in general.

Also related: OP's other question (Lorentz Boosts and Hyperbolic Quaternions)

possibly useful: https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/History_of_Topics_in_Special_Relativity/Lorentz_transformation_(Quaternions)

@naturallyInconsistent Would you mind making an example for the general case in which the direction has a non-zero x-direction, non-zero y-direction and a non-zero z-direction? And does that as well work for an event that also has y- and z-coordinates?

The general pure Lorentz boost matrix looks rather intimidating, and so I had always thought that it would be horrible, but actually it is pretty simple to compute the exponential form directly, if you pay a bit of attention to compute some intermediate steps. I am talking about Equations (43) to (48) in https://bohr.physics.berkeley.edu/classes/221/1112/notes/lorentz.pdf and I cannot remember where in my own output that I had computed this, on this site itself.

@naturallyInconsistent I'm sorry for asking so many things as I don't have much experience in these fields. What would I have to do now in order to obtain the Lorentz Boost formula for the Hyperbolic Quaternions?

It seems like you are not familiar with the standard physics treatments. Trying to learn an esoteric thing, especially one that had proven to fail and thus is a dead end, when you are not yet familiar with the standard known-good presentations, is an extremely bad idea.

also possibly useful: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/28797/

FWIW, the non-associativity of the hyperbolic quarternions seems to kill its usefulness. See also the discussion on the Wikipedia page.
